# Looking for a messenging app

Tags: chat, iphone-app, facebook

Looking for a free iPhone app that will allow me to access Facebook Messenger without installing Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Why you need another app to access messenger app. Use the browser instead.

Comment: @Koder101 texting through the browser on the phone isn’t ideal

Comment: Using a proxy app instead of original, is also not ideal, as it may compromise your security/privacy.